# IE and document.implementation.createDocument() - which arguments effect correct html nodename case?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-9

Chrome and Firefox like document.implementation.createDocument(). IE9 does not, it demands the namespaceURI and document element name are supplied. This means calling something like document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml','html',null), but this has the bizarre effect of generating an html document that does not use the official HTML element nodeName case. It's supposed to be all-uppercase, and a normal document.createElement("a").nodeName in IE9 will return "A". Using the document.impl... version, [...].createElement("a").nodeName returns "a".

Which magical combination of arguments will effect a document that has correct case rules?

(reason for the question: a million QUnit tests that test DOM fragments expect uppercase nodenames, and will throw errors all over the place with this not-windowed element factory. These tests can all be fixed manually to ignore case, but if there's a way to make IE behave, rather than pretend lowercase element names are okay -they're not, according to the spec- I'll take that before doing manual fixing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the createHTMLDocument method instead, like this:

```
document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("").createElement("a").nodeName
```

(almost in keeping with the [DOM4 spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-domimplementation-createhtmldocument)).

createDocument, according to that spec, creates an XML document, which should not coerce the element names to upper case.